# An indicator of how much traffic is on Stackoverflow at the current time

Tags: feature-request, traffic

It would be nice if we had some indicator on the page that gave us an idea of how "hot" Stackoverflow or another trilogy site is at the current time. This could be based on how many answers/questions/edits/whatever happened in the last hour, or whatever.

I personally would like to know when more questions are being asked so I know when I have the opportunity to see more and learn more. **note:** I originally thought I should only ask or answer questions at peek traffic intervals, but the more questions being asked, the quicker yours slips off the list, and the more people on, the more competition you have in answering questions, so traffic isn't always a relevant factor in SO usage. This feature wouldn't be of interest to everyone, so it could possibly be a preference.

*If SO chooses not to implement this feature, it would be great if they could give us some of the specific day-to-day and hour-hour traffic statistics , so we can make a greasemonkey script that tells you how "hot" the specific hour you are one statistically is.*

Answer (score 5):

I just go to the front page, hit the End key, and check out the timestamp of the oldest question on the front page.

Right now it's 15 minutes since the most recent answer or edit on the last question.  With 50 questions on the front page, there have been 200 new questions/answers in the last hour.

During busy times the last question has had new activity only two minutes prior, which indicates 1,500 questions/answers/edits per hour.

It's a quick and easy way to find how busy the site is, and only requires one keystroke when on the front page.

Comment: One keystroke and some mental calculation (helps to loosen the mind after intensive coding/testing/debugging) +1

Answer (score 5):

Here you go. More stats [here](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/stats.html).

[image: questions by hour]
[image: answers by hour]

Comment: Out of curiosity, it that the original question/answer submission time, or time of last edit, or ???

Comment: That's the original question or answer posting time.